# Why does the compiler say that the call is ambiguous in associated types while it isn't?

Tags: rust, ambiguous, associated-types

This code:

```
trait SayHello {
    fn say_hello() { println!("hello") }
}

trait Foo {
    type Hello: SayHello;
}

trait Bar: Foo {
    type Hello: SayHello;
}

struct Generic<T>(T);

impl<T> Generic<T> where T: Bar<Hello = <T as Foo>::Hello> {
    fn say_hello() {
        T::Hello::say_hello()
    }
}
```

returns this error:

```
error[E0221]: ambiguous associated type `Hello` in bounds of `T`
  --> src/lib.rs:17:9
   |
6  |     type Hello: SayHello;
   |     --------------------- ambiguous `Hello` from `Foo`
...
10 |     type Hello: SayHello;
   |     --------------------- ambiguous `Hello` from `Bar`
...
17 |         T::Hello::say_hello()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ambiguous associated type `Hello`
   |
help: use fully qualified syntax to disambiguate
   |
17 |         <T as Foo>::Hello()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: use fully qualified syntax to disambiguate
   |
17 |         <T as Bar>::Hello()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But there shouldn't be any ambiguity. It's clearly stated that the `Hello` associated type is the same in `Foo` and `bar`.

- Why is there an issue?
- Is there a way to make this logic work?

Comment: Bounds can be arbitrarily complex, so the compiler doesn't even try to reason on "Oh but wait, those types happen to be equal" level. It would be easy in that particular case (or would it?), but there's always going to be someone trying one level further than what's implemented.

Comment: @mcarton I think that some languages like Haskell "understand" this kind of bounds and allow such reasoning, but I may be wrong. Anyway, it's "just" a logical system where it's possible to answer the question if 2 types are similar.

Comment: It's not that the compiler can't tell that two types are the same, because you're writing generic code -- there *are* no types, only type *parameters*. Admittedly, a sufficiently smart compiler could recognize that the constraints on the parameters guarantee they are in fact the same type. However, that's still a harder problem than knowing that two *resolved* types are the same. "Queen Elizabeth II is Queen Elizabeth II" is a tautology; "the Monarch of the United Kingdom is the Monarch of Canada" requires higher-order logic even though all three phrases refer to the same person.

Comment: @trentcl So, the answer is just that the type system isn't powerful enough. Prolog or any other logical language can say if something is true/false/indetermined from a set of rules.

Comment: No, actually, I think the answer is that `T::Hello` is simply ambiguous at name resolution time. Name resolution doesn't care about what the types *actually are*, only about the names you use to get to them. This is also why you can call `.borrow()` on a function argument of type `T: Borrow<str>` and get `&str` instead of `&T`, even though `T` definitely also implements `Borrow<T>` -- name resolution only cares about what's declared, not what can be inferred.

Comment: In other words, even if the type system *were* powerful enough to prove that `<T as Foo>::Hello` and `<T as Bar>::Hello` are the same (I don't think it is), it wouldn't matter, because `T::Hello` still has to refer unambiguously to one or the other. Bear in mind `T::Hello` is really just a convenient shorthand for `<T as Trait>::Hello` when `Trait` is unambiguous. Here it is ambiguous.

Comment: @trentcl Alright, it's clearer now. You should update the answer or create your own.

Answer (score 4):

If `T` implements `Bar`, it also *has* to implement `Foo`, as per your bound on the trait. Therefore, `T::Hello` in `say_hello()` can both refer to `<T as Foo>::Hello` or `<T as Bar>::Hello`, which fixes your example.

It'd be possible to introduce another parameter `H: SayHello` and set both `Foo::Hello` and `Bar::Hello` to `H`. Dispatch to `say_hello()` then works via `H::say_hello()`, rather than `T::Hello::say_hello()`.

```
struct Generic<T>(T);

impl<T, H> Generic<T> where T: Bar<Hello=H> + Foo<Hello=H>, H: SayHello {
    fn say_hello() {
        H::say_hello()
    }
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=920368d7c2d4e5eea98465de8b193b9e

Comment: My example isn't complete, but there can also be a `Generic` implementation where that bound isn't needed, *aka* where `Foo::Hello` isn't the same as `Bar::Hello`. Your solution prevents such a thing to exist.

Comment: In that case the second paragraph of my answer should work: specify `T::Hello` as `<T as Bar>::Hello`

Comment: Well, yes, that's the modification proposed by the compiler, but that doesnt answer my first question

Comment: Yep, sorry, I didn't properly read the example. There's another way to express the constraints via `impl<T, H> Generic<T> where T: Bar<Hello=H> + Foo<Hello=H>, H: SayHello` and `H::say_hello()`, which makes it clear to the compiler that both  `Foo::Hello` and `Bar::Hello` are `H`.

Comment: Hey, that's a clever trick, thanks! I still wonder why the compiler doesn't understand my code

Comment: I think the original answer is still essentially correct; see my comments on the question